sync jitpack.io in gradle 7.0+ (with changing settings.gradle) and confront error
after sync below code :
settings.gradle     >>
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()


    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
`        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`
    }
}


rootProject.name = "test"

include ':app'


my error after sync gradle is :
Cannot access 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity' which is a supertype of 'com.example.test.MainActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
and dependency block in build.gradle  >>
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation "com.github.cafebazaar.Poolakey:poolakey:2.2.0"

}

sync jitpack in gradle of android studio  dolphin
and expected have any error
for reproduce my code  create new project and add
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
to repository   setting.gradle

github sample repo to reproduce problem needed

There is no error with your imports, as the message says, there is an error in the classes you are extending, check if it is correct.
You could also try; File -> Invalidate Cache & Restart
